# REPLACE TABLE AS SELECT is not working with parquet whereas it works fine for delta

Tags: apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks

I am working on Azure Databricks, with Databricks Runtime version being - `14.3 LTS (includes Apache Spark 3.5.0, Scala 2.12)`. I am facing the following issue.

Suppose I have a view named `v1` and a database `f1_processed` created from the following command

```sql
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS f1_processed
LOCATION "abfss://processed@formula1dl679student.dfs.core.windows.net/"
```

Then if I run the following command it runs fine.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE f1_processed.circuits
AS
SELECT * FROM v1;
```

However, if I specify the format like in the following code

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE f1_processed.circuits
USING PARQUET
AS
SELECT * FROM v1;
```

An error is thrown

```
[UNSUPPORTED_FEATURE.TABLE_OPERATION] The feature is not supported: 
Table `spark_catalog`.`f1_processed`.`circuits` does not support REPLACE TABLE AS SELECT. 
Please check the current catalog and namespace to make sure the qualified table name is expected, 
and also check the catalog implementation which is configured by "spark.sql.catalog". SQLSTATE: 0A000
```

As seen from the first command, REPLACE TABLE AS SELECT is supported and the error is wrong. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CREATE OR REPLACE command is only supported for DELTA tables. It is specified in the documentation of databricks [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/sql/language-manual/sql-ref-syntax-ddl-create-table-using#:%7E:text=it%20already%20exists.-,This%20clause%20is%20only%20supported%20for%20Delta%20Lake%20tables.,-REPLACE%20preserves%20the). It says as follows.

> REPLACE
>
> If specified replaces the table and its content if it already exists. **This clause is only supported for Delta Lake tables**.

The error might not say directly say this but it is subtly hinting to the parquet format of the table. The statement `Table 'spark_catalog'.'f1_processed'.'circuits' does not support REPLACE TABLE AS SELECT.` says that since the table is created in parquet format, it cannot use the `REPLACE...` command.

Comment: Where in the error were you able to understand that it is indicating `PARQUET` being a problem? The message just says `does not support REPLACE TABLE AS SELECT`

Comment: Can you cite any documentation for reference?

Comment: Let me update in the solution with document link just check if it works for you.
BTW did this 
spark.sql("""
CREATE TABLE f1_processed.circuits02
USING PARQUET
LOCATION "abfss://folder02@newgenstg.dfs.core.windows.net/ADB_Delta_new/"
AS
SELECT *
FROM v1
""")
work at your end?

Comment: Using spark.sql?

Comment: Yeah, the normal `CREATE` works fine. I want to know why is `REPLACE TABLE` working only for delta format?